# how to achieve Node.js's image service

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, d3.js

Recently I have a project to provide image service like this:

1. post data using json to server in client(use python)
2. the webservice on server renders data to png picture using node.js and d3.js(create line chart png image)
3. the server return png image
4. use python to get the image and email it to some people

I am new to d3.js and node.js, and there are many pictures to be rendered so I dont know the performance. How about this solution, and what do I should take attention? Could I get some suggetion? I feel a little fear for this beacuse I cant know if I can achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use cloud providers and nodejs i suggest you take a look at [AwsLambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/getting-started/?nc1=h_ls)

which should fit perfectly for your needs.

Comment: I have achieve it use node.js and d3.js : https://github.com/ubear/hegel